# Windows Phone 8 - Saving a List to IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to save a collection of object that are a type of my class. I get an error stating:

> The collection data contract type 'System.Collections.Generic.List cannot be deserialized because it does not have a public parameterless constructor. 
>   Adding a public parameterless constructor will fix this error.

Here is my class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace MojProjekt
{
    class Lekarna
    {
        public string Ime { get; set; }

        public Lekarna()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I save to the IsolatedStorage:

```
List<Lekarna> lekarneList = new List<Lekarna>();  
// here I then fill the list ...  
IsolatedStorageSettings localStorage = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
localStorage.Add("lekarneList", lekarneList;
localStorage.Save();
```

Comment: When I try to save list in isolatedstorage like you have done, I get System.ArgumentException

Answer (score 6, accepted):

make the class public

`public class Lekarna`